# How to use a comma correctly

Tags: word-usage, commas

Where do I put commas in a sentence like this....?

> Mom told me to buy butter milk a dozen eggs and six apples at the
>   store.

Comment: I would up the answer with the green check-mark if I were you

Answer (score 3):

```
"Mom told me to buy butter, milk, a dozen eggs, and six apples at the store."
```

Comment: hard to improve on that.